# How to match chinese characters with grep?

Tags: vim, grep, cjk

It is verified that `[\u4e00-\u9fff]` can match chinese characters in vim.

```
:%g/[\u4e00-\u9fff]/d
```

The command above can delete all the lines containing chinese characters.

```
ls  /tmp/test
ktop 1_001.png.bak
fonts.dir.bak
New
Screenshot from 2016-09-12 16:50:29.png.bak
你好
```

Now i want to extract files whose name is chinese characters.

```
ls  /tmp/test |grep -P  '[\x4e\x00-\x9f\xff]'
```

The command  can't get files whose name is chinese characters.
How to fix it?

**ls  /tmp/test  |  grep  -v  '[a-z]'** can get it ,but it is what i want.

Comment: Try this `ls  /tmp/test | grep -P "[一-龥]"`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To match just lines (filenames) that have Han (Chinese) characters, you can use `[\p{Han}]` :

```
ls  /tmp/test | grep -P '[\p{Han}]'
```

`\p{Han}` is one [Unicode-script category property usable in any PCRE-supporting engine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script):

```
\p{Common} \p{Arabic} \p{Armenian} \p{Bengali} \p{Bopomofo}
\p{Braille} \p{Buhid} \p{Canadian_Aboriginal} \p{Cherokee}
\p{Cyrillic} \p{Devanagari} \p{Ethiopic} \p{Georgian} \p{Greek}
\p{Gujarati} \p{Gurmukhi} \p{Han} \p{Hangul} \p{Hanunoo} \p{Hebrew}
\p{Hiragana} \p{Inherited} \p{Kannada} \p{Katakana} \p{Khmer} \p{Lao}
\p{Latin} \p{Limbu} \p{Malayalam} \p{Mongolian} \p{Myanmar} \p{Ogham}
\p{Oriya} \p{Runic} \p{Sinhala} \p{Syriac} \p{Tagalog} \p{Tagbanwa}
\p{TaiLe} \p{Tamil} \p{Telugu} \p{Thaana} \p{Thai} \p{Tibetan}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `grep -P '[\p{Han}]'`, nor `grep -P "[一-鿿]"` approach worked on my old version of grep (2.10).
Yet, if the character encoding is guaranteed to be UTF-8, we can always expand the `\u4e00-\u9fff` range down to the byte level:

```sh
ls  /tmp/test |grep -P  '[\xE5-\xE9][\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|\xE4[\xB8-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]'
```

And it worked just fine with my version.